# Izpack, Java - Get the resource path as a variable

Tags: java, variables, path, izpack

During the installation I execute a java class.
I throw some variables from my install.xml file to this java class.

My problem is I see no way to throw the IzPack resource path to this class.
There is no IzPack built-in variable.

But I know it's stored somewhere because I give it to the IzPack compiler :

"...\IzPack\bin\compile" "...\install.xml"   **-b thepathIwouldliketoget**

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

@ command-prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\IzPack\bin>compile -?

.::  IzPack - Version 4.3.5 ::.

.......

-> Command line parameters are : (xml file) [args]  
   (xml file): the xml file describing the installation  
   -h (IzPack home) : the root path of IzPack. This will be needed  
               if the compiler is not called in the root directory  of IzPack.  
               Do not forget quotations if there are blanks in the path.  
   -b (base) : indicates the base path that the compiler will use for filenames  
               of sources. Default is the current path. Attend to -h.
```

just to clarify: `-b <path-name>` is not exactly an `IzPack resource path`. As mentioned above, it's a `base path` used specifically to **resolve other file paths**. it's **default value** would be the **current directory**, i.e. `C:\Program Files\IzPack\bin`, in the example above.

***now, i havent test this, but this path might be accessible  through the property `baseDir`***.
two reasons:

- the `Apache Ant Integration` section [**HERE**](http://izpack.org/documentation/advanced-features.html#apache-ant-integration) specifies this property as `'baseDir'`.
- the file `CliAnalyzer.java` (find it, and other source files, [**HERE**](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-compiler/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/compiler/cli/CliAnalyzer.java)), which analyses the **command-line inputs**, has the following block of code:

  `if (commandLine.hasOption(ARG_BASEDIR)) { 
              baseDir = commandLine.getOptionValue(ARG_BASEDIR).trim();
          }`

probably, the `base path` should be accessible through `${baseDir} or $baseDir`.